# write text below font Awesome icons using css

Tags: css

i want to move the text displayed at the bottom of font Awesome
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBUwA.png)

i just want to use css ,html to make something like in the image

Comment: did you importing the fontawesome script in your HTML file ?

Comment: you shouldn't share it here I'm just asking if you did this step or not remove it, please

Comment: yes i add it ..

Comment: did you tried to add any of the icons in the HTML file because it didn't work with me, is this your issue?

Comment: yes i add font awesome and add icons in html i just want to decorate it using css

Answer (score 0):

1- add container for the icon and the text

2- add center the content in the container

3- add style to the icon

4- you can repeat the icon container to make as many as you want copies

HTML :

```
   <div class="icon-container">
    <i class="fa fa-home icon"></i>  <!-- this should be your icon -->
    <h3>sturdy themes</h3>
    <p>our themes are updated regularly to keep them bug free!</p>
   </div>
```

CSS :

```
.icon-container {
    width: 300px;
    text-align: center;
}

.icon-container p {
    color : #b2b2b2;
}
.icon-container i { 
    color : orange;
    font-size: 100px;
}
```